# How to make POST API calls with google-api-nodejs-client?

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to make a Google Calendar push notification API call (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push).  I figured out how to make a calendar list call.  So, I am fairly confident that my Oauth 2.0 authentication piece is working.  I am guessing that I need to specify that the push notification call is a POST.  Here are my codes:

```
  var params = { calendarId: calendarId,
                 id: 'my-unique-id-00001',
                 type: "web_hook",
                 address: "https://mydomain.com/notifications" };
  client
    .calendar.events.watch(params)
    .withAuthClient(authClient)
    .execute(callback);
```

I keep getting this error message:

{ errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'required',
       message: 'entity.resource',
       debugInfo: 'com.google.api.server.core.Fault: ImmutableErrorDefinition{base=REQUIRED, category=USER_ERROR, cause=com.google.api.server.core.Fault: Builder{base=REQUIRED, ...

Comment: Did you manage to figure this one out? I'm experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: Do you know what your request's content-type is? I've seen this error when it was != application/json

Comment: Strangely, I'm using the google provided google-api-ruby-client and I still need to set Content-Type header to application/json in order to do a watch request. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While I was attempting to watch something using the Google Drive API, I ran into the same issue. The issue turned out to be that some of the parameters need to be in the response body.

In your case I believe that the calendarId needs to be a path parameter and the others need to be in the request body. Something like this should work

```
var pathParams = { calendarId: calendarId };
var bodyParams = {
    id: 'my-unique-id-00001',
    type: 'web_hook',
    address: 'https://mydomain.com/notfications'
};
client
    .calendar.events.watch(pathParams, bodyParams)
    .withAuthClient(authClient)
    .execute(callback);
```